# Cannot read property of undefined:ngModule

Tags: angular, upgrade

After upgrading to Angular 13 (from Angular 4), I started to get the following error `error:Cannot read property of undefined:ngModule`

[image: Console screenshot]

I am at a loss as to how to approach troubleshooting this.

Comment: Please give more details about your issue so we can guess the possible causes. I hope you didn't upgrade from ng4 to ng13 in one shot ? You have to test your app on each version upgrade, so you can see which exact version breaks your app...

Comment: Upgrading in one shot is not the cause, nor would upgrading one version at a time solve the problem. At some point the error would start occurring during the upgrades. What causes this error, and how does one troubleshoot it? These are the questions to be answered.